# AngularJS: Authentication Service supporting a promise?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have setup an authentication service which I inject into my Login controller I then call it to do a login... for example

$scope.login = function() {

```
    var loginResult = authentication.login($scope.model.user, $scope.model.pass);
```

I need to know weather the login was successful or not as I need to peform some logic depending on the result. I could return a bool from login on the authentication service but the problem is that inside my login it calls to a rest service which has a promise. like so

```
       return {
         authenticate: function (username, password) {

            var enc = base64.encode(username + ':' + password);

            AuthRestangular.setDefaultHeaders({'Authorization': 'Basic ' + enc });


            AuthRestangular.one('login').get().then(function (data) {
                isLoggedIn = true;
                return true;
            }, function () {
                return false;
            });
```

So it takes a few seconds for the Rest service to return and it returns a promise i.e. then ....  either true or false. So the service actually returns to the Login Controller before I have the promise.

So I am confused what i should do here, Can i have my service also return a promise?? otherewise the loginResult is always false as it doesn't return in time hence the default for my bool is false.

Any ideas

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not return true false from service instead you should return a promise from the service and use that promise inside controller

```
--service 
return {
         authenticate: function (username, password) {

            var enc = base64.encode(username + ':' + password);

            AuthRestangular.setDefaultHeaders({'Authorization': 'Basic ' + enc });


           return  AuthRestangular.one('login').get();
            });


--controller 

authentication.login($scope.model.user, $scope.model.pass).then(function(data){})
```

Comment: ok, i didn't realize that. Just out of interest if i did want to handle my promise inside my service and then return a "new" promise - would this be much work ?

Comment: yes you can always do it but then you have to create a new promise inside service and return that promise using var deferred = $q.defer();return deferred.promise;